# Using superglue to stick command hook again to the wall

Tags: drywall

I tried to stick my curtain hanger rods to the wall using Command Hooks and it keeps falling down.

I was wondering if I could just use superglue on the Command Hooks to stick them to the wall?

If there is an alternative solution, other than using drills, since I'm in a rental.

Comment: 1) A landlord should install curtain rods or at least allow you to install them.  Only a foolish landlord would refuse, knowing the tenant will probably improvise and damage the apartment.   Did you ask?  2) There are lightweight paper curtains that peel-and-stick to the window frame or window and later peel off easily.  Sometimes they leave a little residue but it's easy to clean off with goo-gone.

Comment: Please revise your post to finish your sentence. Also, add details about your home so we can provide proper answers.

Comment: Wait the landlord would rather you not make screw holes but would be ok with a large square patch being superglued?    This is a poor question.

Answer (score 3):

#### Don't build a better mouse trap

Using super glue to repair a command strip to hang a curtain rod to hang a curtain in a temporary fashion in an rented apartment reminds me of using a trailer hitch, a gas generator, a broken window and a lot of duct tape to install an air conditioner in a car.
[image]

What you want is to find an elegant solution to your actual need. *An easy way to stick on a curtain.* This could be you:
[image]

Simply search for "temporary blinds".  Buy some, stick them on, and you'll have tons of free time to work on your hair!

Comment: There is actually a really good reason for the van picture.   It might seem weird because he is driving but this guy is probably using this van as a camper and it will use 1/50th of the gasoline to run that AC compared to keeping the car on.    The generator is probably being used for whatever else too.   So hillbilly maybe but not everyone has the means to buy an RV.

Comment: There's a similar photo floating around with a sedan, I should have used that one.  As for the likeliness of this van belonging to lovers of the great outdoors ... maybe ... and then at least the exhaust is pointed at the tomatoes and not at the oversized cable entry cutout in the rear window!

Comment: I am not an expert in these setups.   But I live in the midwest and I have seen something along the lines of this 4-5 times at camp grounds.   Obviously I got to go over to the guy and ask what he has going on.   The couple times I chatted, both guys were pretty damn smart and their generator and setup - like this picture - probably worth more than the van.

Comment: They make ceiling mount "temporary blinds" style shower curtains?

Comment: @FreeMan if there is a practical application of that question, make it a Question.  Without additional context there are too many possible answers. I suppose you could buy one of those popup-outdoor-shower springy tenty things and plonk it in the bathtub but that's probably not where you're going with this :).  In a rental only an idiot landlord would not provide a curtain rail knowing without one the tenants will probably flood out the property.

Answer (score 2):

IMO I think you are asking too much of any adhesive to hold curtain rods. Though if you must, I'd go with something OTHER than crazy glue. Gorilla glue comes to mind. Reason being, crazy glue works great if the two surfaces are PERFECTLY FLAT, like gluing a couple pieces of glass together for example. There has to be nearly zero air gap. In your situation, you definitely won't have zero air gap, so something that can fill the gaps well (i.e. gorilla glue) would probably be your best bet.

Comment: It's not the weight of the curtain rods that is the problem... it's the weight of the curtains!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica   Actually it's not the weight of the curtains that would concern me either.   It's the load imparted when somebody opens or closes them.  Pulling on strings or dragging the curtains along the rod will impart alot more stress on the glue joints than the static load of just dead weight.

Answer (score 2):

Even in a rental, it's usually okay to use screws to properly hang a curtain rod holder.  You can always patch the holes if you need to leave and take the rods with you.  Glue is not advised... even if you don't have kids or cats, your friends might and when they come over - they might pull on the curtains.

You might want to consider installing inside-mount blinds.  See also https://www.blinds.com/blog/should-i-install-my-blinds-as-an-inside-or-outside-mount

Answer (score 2):

### Using glue would miss the entire point of using Command hooks.

The point of 3M Command hooks is that when you remove them, they come off clean *IF a careful person carefully follows the instructions, and if they weren't exposed to too much UV light*.

Using super-glue or any kind of glue will completely defeat the purpose of coming off clean later.   There is simply no reason to use Command hooks *at all* at this point!  *So you might as well use the right thing for the job.*

Anyway, Command strips are made for hanging **pictures**.  They can't hang curtain rods - the problem isn't the weight *of the rod*, the problem is the weight *of the curtains!*  **Command strips are not for hanging curtains** and your plan was doomed from the start.

The right thing for hanging curtains is proper hangers made for curtains, with **screws into the wall**.  Obviously you are trying to avoid screws, but it's really not going to work without them.

Comment: You entirely missed the point of why this question is so bad.   How would a landlord not want a screw hole but would be ok with a large square that rips off the face of the wall?    Also the jumbo hooks hold 7.5 so three of them should easily handle curtains.   Still really dumb and not getting how a rod fits... but it would work...   Just dumb.

Comment: The biggest issue isn't even the weight of the curtain, but the _additional forces_ applied when the curtain is opened/closed.

Comment: @FreeMan - you are exactly right but maybe a moot point if no kids are in the house.   When my kids were toddlers they caused at least 3-4 curtain rods to sag and have to be rehung... I just hillbillied it with bigger screws and rehung when they no longer found it fun to hide behind curtains.

Comment: Sometimes, adults will open/close the shower curtain with great vigor - the motion will add stress that a glued (or Command Stripped) attachment that might pull it off, where screws will hold & not even notice.